# Delete from two table using mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table category and subcategory 
I am trying to delete record from this table using `mysql` query

Query is=

```
$sql="Delete t1, t2 From category as t1 
       INNER JOIN  subcategory as t2 on t1.c_id = t2.c_id
       WHERE t1.c_id='$del_c_id' ";
```

This query only delete row from category(t1) whose primary key used into subcategory(t2) table.

Not delete row from category(t1) whose primary key not used in subcategory(t2).

Comment: @xdazz No, he's only deleting one row from category and all the related rows from subcategory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.  By definition LEFT JOIN returns all results from t1, even if they don't have a match in t2.

See this link for more info on join types:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 2):

Try [CASCADE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) option in mysql. Subcategory will be deleted automatically if you delete the category. You need to use the InnoDB storage engine to use this feature.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342852/how-to-use-delete-cascade-on-mysql-myisam-storage-engine) is the accepted answer