# Add foreign key on delete cascade phpMyAdmin is not working

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a main table called `book` with fields `id_book` (primary, unique, auto increment) and `name`.
I have a secondary table called `tag` with fields `book_id` and `tag`

Each book can have many tags. I want that when I delete a book, all the tags to be deleted as well.

I tried this with this:

```
ALTER TABLE tag
ADD FOREIGN KEY (book_id)
REFERENCES book(id_book) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I know I used this block of SQL in the past on some other project and it worked but now it seems it is not working anymore and I don't know why. If I delete a book, the tags will not be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with the SQL in itself, i don't think the problem reside in this particular foreign key.

Maybe the key didn't register or another foreign key is blocking the delete.

I've tested with this SQL file and got the wanted results

```
   CREATE TABLE book (
    id_book INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_book)
);

CREATE TABLE tag (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    book_id INT,
    name VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE tag
ADD FOREIGN KEY (book_id)
REFERENCES book(id_book)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;


INSERT INTO book (`name`) VALUES ("test", "another", "and another");

INSERT INTO tag (`book_id`, `name`) VALUES (1 , "first"), (2, "first"), (1, "second");
```

Comment: the key have been set and I dont have other keys

Comment: You can always check if the keys are indeed on cascade delete with this query 
`select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
where DELETE_RULE ='CASCADE'`

If your key appears and the delete of the rows of the table book do not delete the tags my last guess is a spelling error.
If it doesn't, drop the key and re-create it.

Comment: They are not there. What can be the cause of this?

Comment: I can't find any plausible cause aside from a hiccup when you first created the table. Even if you were to rerun the SQL for the foreign key it would just add another one with the ON DELETE.

Test to drop any existing key with `ALTER TABLE tag DROP <name_of_your_key>`, you can find the name with `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS  where TABLE_NAME = "tag"`

And re-create the key with your SQL statement so you can go from a clean state.

Comment: I have deleted the table, and created it again with your sql code. After that I runed the foreign key code and it is still the same. Can it be related with the MyISAM?

Comment: So that's what it is.
Apparently MyISAM does not feature foreign keys, you'll have to use InnoDB if you want a ON DELETE CASCADE.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342852/how-to-use-delete-cascade-on-mysql-myisam-storage-engine

If you really need to use MyISAM

Comment: I converted my tables to InnoDb but the database remained myisam and i dont have an option to change that

Comment: Checkout the link above

Comment: I updated the my.ini file to load default InnoDB and it worked

Comment: Well, unfortunately not because in your answer you just validate that what I do it's ok and that it should work but it wasn't. So If I did not ask if this can be related with MyISAM (because I have previously read some threads about this thread) the problem would not be solved at this moment. Also, switching to InnoDB was also some personal research. Your answer did not solved the problem but it contributed in a way to it, I think one thumbs up for it reflects better this situation. Thanks